# Disable core dump for SIGHUP signal

Tags: bash, unix, freebsd, coredump

I'm trying to disable core dumps being generated for individual signals in my application.

`ulimit -c 0` wont work in my case, since it needs to be executed before application start and will completely disable core dumps for all signals.

Is it possible to make such an exception for a single signal or at least disable core dump generation for a certain amount of time (eg. during sending the SIGHUP signal)?

Comment: Do you still want the program to abort on receiving SIGHUP, or ignore it?

Comment: @ephemient I'm aborting my application on SIGHUP.

Comment: Ah. Then you'll need to modify the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static sigjmp_buf sigjmp;
static void sighup_handler(int signo) {
    siglongjmp(&sigjmp, signo);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct sigaction sighup_action = {
        .sa_handler = &sighup_handler,
        .sa_flags = SA_RESETHAND,
    };
    sigset_t sigset;
    int signo;

    sigemptyset(&sighup_action.sa_mask);
    sigaddset(&sighup_action.sa_mask, SIGHUP);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sighup_action.sa_mask, &sigset);
    sigaction(SIGHUP, &sighup_action, NULL);
    signo = sigsetjmp(&sigjmp, 1);
    if (signo) {
        struct rlimit rl = { .rlim_cur = 0, .rlim_max = 0 };
        setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &rl);
        sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &sigset, NULL);
        kill(getpid(), signo);
        abort();  /* just in case */
        _exit(128 | signo);
    }
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &sigset, NULL);

    pause(); /* or whatever the rest of your program does */
}
```

You can install a signal handler which sets `RLIMIT_CORE` to 0, then proceeds with the default signal action. If you use `SA_RESETHAND`, the default signal handler is automatically reinstalled right before the signal handler is run. However, `setrlimit` is not async-signal-safe, so we should not call it from inside a signal handler, hence using `siglongjmp` to return to normal code and performing it there.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: siglongjmp does not remove the async-signal-safe requirement of the following code. Using siglongjmp is almost always a sign that you are just completely ignoring the safeness requirements. So it's more readable to just call setrlimit in the handler. See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/siglongjmp.3.html . """recommends avoiding the use of these functions from signal handlers and goes on to point out that if these functions are called from a signal handler [...], the behavior is undefined if the program subsequently makes a call to a non-async-signal-safe function."""

Answer (score 0):

Just add an empty signal handler for SIGHUP, or ignore it like this:

```
signal(SIGHUP, SIG_IGN);
```

Comment: This doesn't abort when the signal is received, which is apparently something the original questioner is interested in.